# Expandable list with edit text on grouplayput in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have created an expandable ListView, in which I have created a custom group layout.

On the group layout I have created an EditText on the right side. Whenever I put text on the EditText and click on the expandable list, the list does not expand/collapse.

When I do focusable false of EditText then list is expand/collapse.

How to solve this problem? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Text is itself a focus-sable component. If we place inside the list view, expandable list then the list click and collapse expand property will not work. *Same problem arose when you use EditText, Button, ImageButton, etc,*

So you need to use:

1.Use following property in Expandable List :

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

or
2. Use the following property in EditText

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Hello, I have edit fandroid:focusable="false" on edit text filed.But I am facing new problem that I am not write text on edit box.

Answer (score 1):

Today,I have resolved the above problem on expandable List and N-Level expandable list view.
I have attached the code. 
Firstly,I have set focusable false of edit text on your activity/adapter,do not on xml of EditText.

```
EditText.setFocusable(false);
```

Secondly,I have used touch listener because here I set focusable true of edit text.So that I can easily type text on edit box.

```
EditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

After that, I have used KeyListener because here I am getting data and set value on hash map according to position/group position.so that whenever I am clicked on 2-level or N-level expandable list view data is not changed.That is very important on expandable list view.On done key press I am hiding keyboard.And set focusable false of edit text,so that I can expand/collapse freely.

```
EditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            String editValue;
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    editValue=groupHolder.numberEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                    EditText.setFocusable(false);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY,0);
                }
                setEditValueHashMap.put(groupPosition, editValue);
                return false;
            }
        });
```